# How do I structure BDD style tests in multiple files?

Tags: jasmine, mocha.js, karma-runner

How does a BDD-style (mocha, jasmine, etc.) large wrapped single `describe()` get broken down into multiple files. I have a 5,000-line unit test file, all of it wrapped as follows:

```
describe('services',function(){
  describe('serviceA',function(){...});
  describe('serviceB',function(){...});
  describe('serviceC',function(){...});
  describe('serviceD',function(){...});
  // .....
  describe('serviceN',function(){...});
});`
```

For sanity's sake I would like to break each one ('serviceA','serviceB',...,'serviceN') into its own file. But I want each to still be inside `describe("services")`.

I see 2 methods:

- use require in the parent: `describe('serviceA',require('./services/serviceA'));` (repeat lots of times)
- have some wrapper include them all

I don't like the second method, since it requires a lot of keeping of file name, `require()` and `describe()` in sync (and thus violates DRY).

I prefer each file *know* what it is testing, and not have to explicitly add the path, rather just have the testrunner intelligently include everything in `'./services'`, and thus have inside `serviceA.js`:

```
describe('serviceA', function() {
   // ....
});
```

but then I need some way to "wrap" 'serviceA' inside 'services'. Is there any way to do that?

In this case, I am testing an angular app via karma, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine's `describe` has no special meaning for loading of files. It's a descriptor. What's stopping you from just doing this?

Karma config:

```
files: [
    'src/services/**/*.js',
    'tests/services/**/*.js'
]
```

serviceA.spec.js

```
describe('services', function () {
    describe('serviceA', function () {

    });
});
```

serviceB.spec.js

```
describe('services', function () {
    describe('serviceB', function () {

    });
});
```

Comment: that is what I did in the end. Didn't love it, but I did it.